# What's the most straight-forward way to prove Walras's Law?

Tags: economics

[Walras' Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walras%27_law) states that summation of pi Ei(p) = 0 for all pi.
We define Ei(p) = xi(p) - qi(p) - Ri.
What are the next steps that I should take?

Comment: I don't quite know what your notation is. The proof starts by asserting LNS preferences and claiming walras' law,  $\forall p,w$ and , $x \in x(p,w), p\cdot x=w $  The proof is almost always handled by contradiction.  You can see most any micro textbook for the full proof.  A good start would be to define your assumptions (LNS?) and the various functions you've specified (you'd have to do that for a proper proof anyway.)

Comment: @Jason B - what's LNS?

Comment: Local non-satiation. It's the claim that, for any point $x$ and any number $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $x'$ in the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$ such that $x'$ is strictly preferred to $x$.

Comment: @Patience the most straightforward proof of Walras' Law requires one to assume LNS preferences and little more (it is implicit in Zermelo's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $i$ denote an agent; $j$ denote the good.

Walras' law: $p.e(p)=0$ for all $p$.

Start with the budget constraint:

$\sum_{j} p_j.x_{ij}=\sum_{j} p_j.w_{ij}$ where $w_{ij}$ is $i$'s endowment of good $j$, $x_{ij}$ is $i$'s consumption of good $j$.

In other words, $\sum_{j} p_{j}.e_{ij}=0$, where $e_{ij}=x_{ij}-w_{ij}$.

Now just add over all agents $i$. You get $\sum_{j}p_j.e_j=0$, where $e_j=\sum_i e_{ij}$ for each $j$. This is Walras' Law. Note that this applies to ALL $p$ - regardless of whether it's the equilibrium price.

Comment: Use the dollar sign ($) for Latex. `${p_j * x_{ij}}$` for ${p_j * x_{ij}}$

Comment: thanks a lot haha I kept using # instead and got nowhere.

Comment: by the way, for your specific question (where there is production too) replce $w_j$ for every good $j$ by $w_j+R_j$